# Simulate undo with detach();

Tags: jquery

The undo button only appends the last detached`.item` and does not allow for appending detached items beyond the last removed. The goal is to remove as many items as I wish and have them restored in succession with each click of the undo button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cacheDom = "";
  $('.remove').click(function() {
    if ($('.item').length > 0) {
      cacheDom = $('.item');
      $(this).closest('.item').detach();
    }
  });
  $('#undo').click(function() {
    $('.list').append(cacheDom);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    Item 1
    <button class='remove'>Remove</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 2
    <button class='remove'>Remove</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 3
    <button class='remove'>Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
<button id='undo'>Undo</button>
```

Comment: Right now `cacheDom` is a jQuery object containing a list of elements with the class 'item' at the time `remove` was called. Seems like what you actually want is to detach the element and append it to a hidden element. Then, when you click "Undo", detach the element from your hidden element and reattach to your visible list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep an array of the elements removed, and restore them, beginning with the first element in the array.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var removedItems = [];
  
  $('.remove').click(function() {
    var removeItem = $(this).closest('.item').detach();
    removedItems.push(removeItem);
  });
  
  $('#undo').click(function() {
    if (removedItems.length) {
      var restoreItem = removedItems.shift();
      $('.list').append(restoreItem);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    Item 1
    <button class='remove'>Remove</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 2
    <button class='remove'>Remove</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 3
    <button class='remove'>Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
<button id='undo'>Undo</button>
```